# Sort Output List by Search Value

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, sorting

Consider the following input:

```
ClearAll[dice, sides];
dice := 3
sides := 6
CountsBy[Times @@@ Tuples[Range[1, sides], dice], {1, sides^dice}]
```

This gives the output

```
<|{1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](1)->1,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](2)->3,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](3)->3,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](4)->6,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](5)->3,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](6)->9,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](8)->7,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](10)->6,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](12)->15,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](9)->3,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](15)->6,
  ...
```

That is acceptable but I would like the output to be sorted after the values that I multiply, i.e., I would like the number of times the product is 9 to be printed between the number of times the product is 8 and the number of times the product is 10. That is, I would like the output to be

```
<|{1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](1)->1,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](2)->3,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](3)->3,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](4)->6,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](5)->3,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](6)->9,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](8)->7,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](9)->3,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](10)->6,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](12)->15,
  {1,216}\[InvisibleApplication](15)->6,
  ...
```

but how do I get this?

P.S. The "problem" occures several times later in the output list, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have those entries sorted then the result will be sorted too:

```
CountsBy[
    Sort[Times @@@ Tuples[Range[1, sides], dice]]
  , {1, sides^dice}
]
```

but the fastest would probably be just a `KeySort`:

```
KeySort @ CountsBy[
    Times @@@ Tuples[Range[1, sides], dice]
  , {1, sides^dice}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer @Kuba's method of `KeySort`. You can always use `Normal`then `SortBy` and then `Association`

```
ClearAll[dice, sides];
dice := 3
sides := 6
<| SortBy[First]@Normal@CountsBy[
Times @@@ Tuples[Range[1, sides], dice], {1, sides^dice}] |>
```

Comment: You know you can express your preferences by upvoting answers :)

Comment: @Kuba +1 for the comment :)